# Cursor get temp/result table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I have the table of lecturers, their subjects and exp within this subj:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Full Name | varchar(30) |
| Experience | int |
| Subj | varchar(10) |

I have to obtain for each subject the sequence of lecturers whose exp % 5 = 0, separated by comma. Like

| subj | names tuple |
| --- | --- |
| subj1 | lecturer_name1, lecturer_name2, ... |
| subj2 | lecturer_name1, lecturer_name2, ... |
| subj3 | lecturer_name1, lecturer_name2, ... |

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_unqualified_lectures
AS

DECLARE @subj varchar(10)

DECLARE my_cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT(subj) FROM Lecturers

OPEN my_cur
DECLARE @res_table TABLE (subj varchar(20), names varchar(max))
DECLARE names_tupple varchar(max)
FETCH NEXT FROM my_cur INTO @subj

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SELECT @names_tupple = FullName FROM Lecturers WHERE Experience % 5 = 0

    // I have no idea how to concat the names

    INSERT INTO @res_table VALUES(@subj, @names_tupple)

    FETCH NEXT FROM my_cur INTO @subj
END

CLOSE my_cur
DEALLOCATE my_cur
GO
```

Would you recommend how to modify it properly, or something better than I came up?

Note: Feasibly I missed something or performed something wrong. It's not been tested, I just used paper and pen.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of SQL, you can put this inside of your cursor to concatenate the names.  You'll need to play with it to get your original reference for the `subj`.

```
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + names
    FROM @res_table
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

EDIT:

With SQL Server 2017 and above, you could use this which would also get you the `subj` reference.

```
SELECT subj,STRING_AGG( ISNULL(names, ' '), ',') As names_tupple 
       From @res_table
GROUP BY subj
```